# (Vuetify) V-switch with non-label text

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a v-switch element in Vuetify with an associated text, but I do not want a label attached to the text. I simply want to create a switch with text that is not clickable (because the switch should be only for the toggle in some cases for the scenario of sensitive data).

Here's my code:
https://codepen.io/groove-theory/pen/dyRyRxE

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
             <v-switch label="label_text"></v-switch>
      <span>non_label_text</span>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

I've tried to have a span outside the switch but that doesn't do the trick. I would just love to have the label text there but not as a label. But I'm not sure if Vuefity has this functionality.

Comment: Well, simply create a Flexbox container and put there your `v-switch` without a label (as first Flex child) and then a DIV with your unclickable text (as second Flex child).

Answer (score 1):

<sub>***Disclaimer***: Removing label's ability to change the switch value removes an accessibility feature. In some countries, this could be classified as discrimination against certain categories of (impaired) users. Public companies using the code below might be liable in those countries.</sub>

---

**Solution 1:**

Remove the `label` value from `<v-switch>` and use a `.d-inline-flex align-center` wrapper to align it with whatever you want:

```html
  <div class="d-inline-flex align-center">
    <v-switch></v-switch>
    <div class="mb-1">lol</div>
  </div>
```

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/RwQqWmG).

---

**Solution 2:**

Apply `pointer-events: none` to the switch label:

```html
  <v-switch label="lol" class="inert-label"></v-switch>
```

```css
.inert-label .v-label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

See it [here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/RwQqrPK).

---

Side query: are you sure what you're trying to achieve can't be done by toggling `<v-switch>`'s `disabled` property?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    disabled: false,
    lol: true
  }),
  computed: {
    btnText() {
      return `${this.disabled ? 'En' : 'Dis'}able switch`
    },
    disabledStatement() {
      return `Switch is ${this.disabled ? 'dis' : 'en'}abled.`
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-switch label="lol" :disabled="disabled" v-model="lol"></v-switch>
      <hr>
      {{ disabledStatement }}
      <v-btn @click="disabled = !disabled">{{btnText}}</v-btn>     
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Disabling the label while the switch still works feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `width: 0` to your v-switch style

demo here - https://codepen.io/rxch/pen/gOvZzLg

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31985572)